# alertが表示されない

Tags: javascript, html

**現象**
「適正体重を表示」ボタンを押しても、alertが表示されない。

**期待値**
index.htmlの「適正体重を表示」ボタンを押したら、alertが表示される。

**再現手順**
下のHTMLで記述されたファイルとJavaScriptで記述されたファイルを、同じディレクトリで実行する。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>formに身長を入力すると、適正体重がダイアログに表示される</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>formに身長を入力すると、適正体重が表示ダイアログに表示されます</h3>
    <form>
        <input id="height" name="height" type="number" />
        <input id="btn" type="button" value="適正体重を表示" />
    </form>
   <script src="dialog.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

dialog.js

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById('btn').addEvemtListener('click', function() {
        var height = document.getElementById('height');
        var appropriateWeight = new Function('height', 'return height ** 2 * 22;');
        window.alert('適正体重:' + appropriateWeight(height) + 'kg');
    });
});
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('btn').addEvemtListener` でスペルミスがあります。

Comment: 関数やメソッドの名前に関して、modern な IDE(例えば Visual Studio Code など)であれば completion(入力補完)機能が働いて自動的に挿入してくれますし、signature やドキュメントなども表示されます。綴りの間違いで時間を割かれることも無くなるかと思いますので IDE などの利用をお勧めします。

Comment: 余計なことですが、綴りの間違いを直して alert が表示される様になったとしても表示される内容(適正体重)は期待しているものとは異なるものになるでしょう。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEvemtListener('click', function() {
                                  ^^^^^
```

この部分を打ち間違えています。